# WebView, html5, android 4.1.2

Tags: android

Использую WebView для отображения видео html5. 
Код:

```
videoWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.videoWebView);
videoWebView.setWebChromeClient(new VideoWebChromeClient());
videoWebView.setWebViewClient(new VideoWebViewClient());        
videoWebView.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
videoWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
videoWebView.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
videoWebView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
videoWebView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
videoWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
videoWebView.loadUrl(url);
```

ещё вчера всё работало и отлично грузилось. Но сегодня андроид на устройстве обновился до версии 4.1.2 и видео больше не загружается. В лог выводится следующее сообщение:
<GATE-M>DEV_ACTION_COMPLETED</GATE-M>

Что изменилось в этой версии, что более не грузятся видео? Прошу о помощи :)

Comment: на гелакси s2 оказывается, что система выдаёт тоже сообщение, версия андроида на нём 4.0.3ю на планшете гелакси таб 2 работает всё нормально и на телефоне аштиси с версией 2.3.3

Comment: Попробуй вставь в манифест: `<application android:hardwareAccelerated="true" ...>` - нутром чую связано с движком OpenGL

Comment: не помогает) это ещё вчера пробовала)

Answer (score 1):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13071528/html5-canvas-issues-on-android-4-1-1
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12804710/android-4-html5-canvas-not-redrawing

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=37529
http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=39183